# SQL 2012 SSRS Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

While implementing SSRS I am able to access the https://.com/reports and I am able to add new users and sys admins.

When a user that I have added as a sys admin tries to login the get the following error,

> User 'DOMAIN\user' does not have required permissions. Verify that
>   sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account
>   Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

Although They are able to select Site Settings and Manage security settings they are still unable to see the home page.

Comment: Hi Joe, by https://.com/reports, I assume you mean to say your report server?  Where did you add "new users and admin"?  I assume you mean on the report server site.  They would have to be on the home page to see the site settings link in the top right. Where can they select the site settings and manage security settings?  How is that different than the reports homepage?

Comment: Yes, they are on the home page, but that is where they receive the error. 

[Link](http://i.imgur.com/xLjbt8e.jpg)

I may just not have a very good understanding of permissions for this but I am under the assumption that being the user that is attempting to login has been given System Administrator rights under Site Settings> Security on the report server site, I assumed they would have access to everything.

Comment: In 2008, you would have to look at the security settings for the home page found in, home> properties > security.  This is where you would add the new role assignment.  Check to see if there is an equivalent in 2012.  It sounds like you might have just added them to the top level (site settings> security).

Comment: I am not seeing anything like Home> Properties. 

I have created a folder and attempted to give the user permissions directly to the folder and that does not seem to do the trick either.

Comment: ok, last try:  In Internet Explorer, Tools, Options, Advanced, Checkmark on Enable integrated windows authentication.  In Tools, Options, Security, Local Intranet, Sites, Advanced, add the reportserver (localhost) there.  In Tools, Options, security, Custom level, at the bottom, choose Automatic logon only if in intranet zone.  Close browser and retry.   If still doesn't work, for the last step choose Automatic logon with current name and password and retry.

Comment: Have you tried telling them to run IE as an administrator? What happens if they use another browser (Firefox for example). That way you could know if it is a report server setting or a client/network setting that is causing this issue.